# Realm 5.15.0 and up to latest version (6.0.2), fails gradle sync

Tags: android, android-studio, realm, realm-mobile-platform

We are using Realm as our DB framework for Android. Current working version is 5.14.0. Yesterday we tried upgrading to 6.0.2 and gradle sync failed. I then pushed back the versions and saw that starting from 5.15.0 Realm causes gradle sync to fail with errors:

```
ERROR: Failed to resolve: io.realm:realm-android-library:5.15.0
ERROR: Failed to resolve: io.realm:realm-annotations:5.15.0
```

and a few other dependencies failing with the same exact error (but these might be affected by the first fail)

When I tried version 5.14 again, I got no errors and every thing was fine.
I checked the gradle build log and I could see this line appearing MANY times:

```
WARN - un.AndroidRunConfigurationBase - Can't get application ID: Android module missing
```

And a few like these:

```
WARN - roid.tools.ndk.GradleWorkspace - NDK support for project 'project.name' is disabled because the project doesn't contain any valid native configurations.
```

and some:

```
INFO - ty.VersionCompatibilityChecker - Failed to find version reader for component 'android-gradle-experimental-plugin'
```

one of these:

```
INFO - pl.ProjectRootManagerComponent - project roots have changed
```

and eventually:

```
INFO - e.project.sync.GradleSyncState - Gradle sync failed (50 s 766 ms)
```

It looks like the sync starts `SYNC_TASK_CREATED`, some libraries download and then `SETUP_STARTED`. It then fails almost right away.

Does anyone have any idea what is going on here and maybe possible reasons why this might fail? I can add any extra info you may need.

Thanks.

**EDIT:**
I just ran ./gradlew check --stacktrace to get some more info on what is causing the issue and I get this:

```
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app-name:testProdReleaseUnitTest'.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app-name:prodReleaseUnitTestRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not find io.realm:realm-android-library:5.15.0.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/io/realm/realm-android-library/5.15.0/realm-android-library-5.15.0.pom
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/io/realm/realm-android-library/5.15.0/realm-android-library-5.15.0.jar
       - https://jitpack.io/io/realm/realm-android-library/5.15.0/realm-android-library-5.15.0.pom
       - https://jitpack.io/io/realm/realm-android-library/5.15.0/realm-android-library-5.15.0.jar
       - https://maven.fabric.io/public/io/realm/realm-android-library/5.15.0/realm-android-library-5.15.0.pom
       - https://maven.fabric.io/public/io/realm/realm-android-library/5.15.0/realm-android-library-5.15.0.jar
       - https://github.com/uPhyca/stetho-realm/raw/master/maven-repo/io/realm/realm-android-library/5.15.0/realm-android-library-5.15.0.pom
       - https://github.com/uPhyca/stetho-realm/raw/master/maven-repo/io/realm/realm-android-library/5.15.0/realm-android-library-5.15.0.jar
       - http://maven.batch.com/release/io/realm/realm-android-library/5.15.0/realm-android-library-5.15.0.pom
       - http://maven.batch.com/release/io/realm/realm-android-library/5.15.0/realm-android-library-5.15.0.jar
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/io/realm/realm-android-library/5.15.0/realm-android-library-5.15.0.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/io/realm/realm-android-library/5.15.0/realm-android-library-5.15.0.jar


Caused by: org.gradle.internal.resolve.ModuleVersionNotFoundException: Could not find io.realm:realm-android-library:5.15.0.
Searched in the following locations:
  - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/io/realm/realm-android-library/5.15.0/realm-android-library-5.15.0.pom
  - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/io/realm/realm-android-library/5.15.0/realm-android-library-5.15.0.jar
  - https://jitpack.io/io/realm/realm-android-library/5.15.0/realm-android-library-5.15.0.pom
  - https://jitpack.io/io/realm/realm-android-library/5.15.0/realm-android-library-5.15.0.jar
  - https://maven.fabric.io/public/io/realm/realm-android-library/5.15.0/realm-android-library-5.15.0.pom
  - https://maven.fabric.io/public/io/realm/realm-android-library/5.15.0/realm-android-library-5.15.0.jar
  - https://github.com/uPhyca/stetho-realm/raw/master/maven-repo/io/realm/realm-android-library/5.15.0/realm-android-library-5.15.0.pom
  - https://github.com/uPhyca/stetho-realm/raw/master/maven-repo/io/realm/realm-android-library/5.15.0/realm-android-library-5.15.0.jar
  - http://maven.batch.com/release/io/realm/realm-android-library/5.15.0/realm-android-library-5.15.0.pom
  - http://maven.batch.com/release/io/realm/realm-android-library/5.15.0/realm-android-library-5.15.0.jar
  - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/io/realm/realm-android-library/5.15.0/realm-android-library-5.15.0.pom
  - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/io/realm/realm-android-library/5.15.0/realm-android-library-5.15.0.jar
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok that was stupid.
I really should give the error messages more credit...

I added

```
mavenLocal()
jcenter()
```

to

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
}
```

in the root build.gradle file and now it found the Realm repo. Hehe.
Thanks to all the viewers of this question.

Comment: This issue cost me 2 hours. Thanks for the fix!